pyqtSignal emit multi type
I have a signal to be: auto_dj_start = pyqtSignal(dict,str,dict,str)
Sometimes when the player list is empty i want to emit None to all parameters instead of dicts and string.
But this error happens:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\Documents\My Projects\papinhio-player\src\python+\main-window\../..\python+\main-window\page-4\player-list.py", line 721, in run
    self.auto_dj_start.emit(data["play"],data["play-sequence"],data["load"],data["load-sequence"])
TypeError: Player_List_Emitter.auto_dj_start[dict, str, dict, str].emit(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

So what i can do is to emit empty dict and empty string.
Is there any other alternative?
Maybe if i made a new type to be dict_or_None to be dict or None and pass it to pyqtSignal creation.

There's no real solution to this. The best you can do is: auto_dj_start = pyqtSignal(object, object, object, object). Alternatively, if you want to preserve type information, you could take a completely different approach and define a NamedTuple for the signal parameters.

Is it a real problem to emit the signal with empty dict and string? If you need to differentiate between an empty value and None, then you should probably consider using a different signal specific to that case, which would be more consistent. If it's only done for code simplicity you may consider a common function with keyword arguments (defaulting the dict fields to None) and actually emit the signal from there. One other possibility is to use signal overloads, or just use object instead of dict and str in the signal declaration.

Try it:
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
#    auto_dj_start = pyqtSignal(dict, str, dict, str)
    auto_dj_start = pyqtSignal(object)                               # 1
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()

        self.button = QPushButton('Click me')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        self.auto_dj_start.connect(self.onStart)                     # 2
        
    def onClick(self):
        _data = [
            [dict, str, dict, str],
            None,
        ]    
        object = random.choice(_data)    
        self.auto_dj_start.emit(object)                               # 3
        
    def onStart(self, obj):                                           # 4
        self.textBrowser.append(str(obj))
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


